# Implementing queue in C

Tags: c, data-structures, queue, implementation

```
struct client
{
char Fname[20];
char Lname[20];
char home_num[10];
char cell_num[10];
char email_add[20];
int client_id;
}; /* ending the client struct*/

char Main_Menu()
{
 char sel;

 int rear=-1;
 int front=-1;
 client clientQueue [size]; -->I keep having an error come up right here, not sure why.
 int isFull(int rear);
 int isEmpty(int rear);
```

Where I get the error is the line where I am declaring the queue.
Not quite sure why I'm getting that error because when I researched that's what I found.
p.s size is 20

Comment: What error do you get?  Does it happen at compile or run time?

Comment: @simonc the error occurs when compiling. the error says... error: expected ';' before 'clientQueue'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think declaration error, You need to declare like this:

```
struct client  clientQueue [size];
// ^ add struct key work before client
```

And second `size` must be a constant value, defined at compilation time.

better to use macro like below:

```
# define SIZE 100


struct client  clientQueue [SIZE];
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I declared size as a constant value.

Comment: @user1 Size values has to be known at compilation time.

Comment: Yes, I did this. Thanks.

Comment: @user1 Good additionally use struct before client every where in your code.

Comment: Oh I was wondering about that, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If this is pure `C`, you must use the `struct`-keyword

```
struct client clientQueue [size];
```

And `size` must be defined somwhere, too.

Or use `typedef` like

```
typedef struct client {
    char Fname[20];
    char Lname[20];
    char home_num[10];
    char cell_num[10];
    char email_add[20];
    int client_id;
} client;
```

Comment: If I use typedef does this mean I don't have to type struct in front of client each time it is used? @bash.d

Comment: Yes! This true. Typedef defines an alias for a type. And you can then omit the `struct`-keyword.

Answer (score 1):

As you are coding in c, you need to use the keyword struct while declaring new variables of struct type or use typedef

```
struct client clientQueue [size];
```